# Dynamically selecting the gpt version for given payload requirement of tokens

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am trying an approach which provides me the functionality to upgrade my GPT-3.5-turbo-4K to
16K when ever i have a payload which does not satisfy with the current payload window of 4k tokens

I am currently using pinecone to store the vector data and langchain to manage the openai calles and other chains

My current approach is to manually choose the satisfying version of Gpt-3.5
in which i calculate the number of token that i am receiving from the vector database with my query
and then add other token counts for prompt and instructions that we use in langchain

if the calculation reaches near 3750 we change the model name GPT-3.5-Trubo-4k to GPT-3.5-Trubo-16k
(adding a buffer for completion token to generate propper answer for my usecase)

```py
llm = OpenAIConstants.get_answer_llm()
prompt = AnswerGenerationConstants.PROMPT.value

total_token_count = get_token_count(relevant_documents, query)
if OpenAIConstants.BASE_ANSWER_MODEL_MAX_LIMIT.value - 250.0 < total_token_count:
    llm = OpenAIConstants.get_answer_llm(max=True)
```

but this is yet a static switch, it would be useful if we can find any dynamic support from lang-chain or other equivalents